# The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths. laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5, configuration, installation

I installed a new fresh copy of Laravel 5.3 using composer but I'm getting this error:

> The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the
>   correct key lengths. Even though my app.php file in config directory specify
>    'cipher' => 'AES-128-CBC'

Comment: Refer to this github [issue][1].

Comment: i have this issue and it is totally random... 90% of my requests go through without any errors, then i get one HTTP 500 with this in the logs.

Comment: If it is a fresh install, then create the symlink of storage in public directory with this command: php artisan storage:link

Answer (score 164):

You need to have **.env** on your appication folder then run:

```
$ php artisan key:generate
```

If you don't have **.env** copy from **.env.example**:

```
$ cp .env.example .env
```

Comment: I am also having this exact problem on a fresh install. I've run the key generator, cleared and re-cached. I checked the .env file and the key was successfully inserted but the error persists.

Comment: @Rottingham, in your config/app.php what do you have as 'key' and 'cipher'?

Comment: I had the same, AES-256-CBC as the ciper, and the KEY was env('APP_KEY'); I discovered my problem was key:generate was concatenating they key in the `.env` file instead of replacing it.

Comment: I'm also getting the same error.I followed all the mention steps but still it's same.Works fine in local environment.But not works in hostgator environment.

Comment: @CodeCanyon have you tried checking key length as suggested by http://stackoverflow.com/a/40709643/1008916?

Comment: @MugomaJ.Okomba - Yes i checked it.It's correct.And this works fine in my local apache server.Only issue with online server.But i followed same steps in both scenarios.

Comment: "Just run these commands" is not a very good answer. While it may solve the problem, it offers no deeper understanding of what, exactly is being done. Nor does it answer whether these values should be the same on a production server versus a development server versus one's workstation.

Comment: If you have already cached your config, run `php artisan config:cache` again after generating new key.

Answer (score 31):

Run this commands on your terminal:

`php artisan config:clear`

then

`php artisan config:cache`

Comment: Just as a P.S. or FYI - running config:cache automatically runs config:clear as you see in the terminal when running config:cache

Comment: I had a .env file and a APP_KEY value, this works in my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

Ok, this has basically already been answered, but I found a couple caveats that had be consternated, or constipated, one of those two...

First, as has already been said, you should ensure you have a valid `.env` file which you can accomplish in the terminal by copying the existing `.env.example` file as such:

`$ cp .env.example .env`

Then, generate your application Key

`$ php artisan key:generate`

Once this is done, make sure to open your .env file and ensure that the APP_KEY line looks correct - this is where my consternation came from:

`APP_KEY=base64:MsUJo+qAhIVGPx52r1mbxCYn5YbWtCx8FQ7pTaHEvRo=base64:Ign7MpdXw4FMI5ai7SXXiU2vbraqhyEK1NniKPNJKGY=`

**You'll notice that the key length is wrong, it for some unknown reason (probably from running key:generate multiple times) has two `base64=` keys in there. Removing one is the fix to the problems I was having and this appears to be an Artisan/Laravel bug.**

Hope this answer helps anyone who may be struggling with the same problems or annoying bug.

Comment: I'm facing this issue as well, but it only pops up every now and then. Key is correct, so I assume there's some other problem going on. I've done the config caching, suggested by Lee, and will see how it goes. For reference, I have a whole bunch of other access tokens in the file, so one of them *could* be causing an issue. However, if they were, I'd expect it to happen every time. (L5.4)

Comment: This, plus doing `php artisan config:clear` then `php artisan config:cache`, fixed my installation.

Comment: @MikeRockétt There is discussion here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9080 
regarding multiple ajax calls pulling the app_key at the same time and .env file being locked from the first call. Recommended fix is to not call the .env in production but using the cache?

Comment: That's it !!! Fixed for me. I got two keys! Removed one and worked :)

Comment: your text in bold helped me. thanks

Answer (score 17):

in `.env` file give this key and you are done

```
APP_KEY=ABCDEF123ERD456EABCDEF123ERD456E
```

Still not working?

If you are working from cli, reboot the server and it will.

Want explanation?

ok, as the error message says:

> The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the
>   correct key lengths.

Key length for `AES-128-CBC` is 16 characters e.g ABCDEF123ERD456E

Key length for `AES-256-CBC` is 32 characters e.g ABCDEF123ERD456EABCDEF123ERD456E

Make sure in `config/app.php` the `cipher` is set to the appropriate cipher like the two above and the key is pointing to the `.env` file  `APP_KEY` variable. My app has the `AES-256-CBC` cipher set, so i gave it the 32 characters key
like `APP_KEY=ABCDEF123ERD456EABCDEF123ERD456E` and everything worked just fine after that.

Answer (score 10):

If you are running a Laravel project for the first time in that machine make sure you have the necessary [requirements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation).
Open your CMD/Terminal in your project directory or

```
cd to/your/project/dir
```

Give this command again:

```
composer update
```

Change your `.env.example` to `.env` and make necessary changes in that file especially database configurations to avoid db error.
Then

```
php artisan key:generate
```

This solves this AES cipher key length problem every time I create a Laravel project or clone it from git.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to just check is that your .env file is in the www-data group (or httpd or whatever your web server group is) and that the group has read permission.

On linux my permissions looked like this when I got this error:

`-rw-rw-r-- 1 kevin kevin 618 Mar 16 09:32 .env`

I then just removed read permission for all and removed write permission for group.

`chmod 640 .env`

Then I changed the group to www-data

`chown kevin:www-data .env`

My permissions now look like this:

`-rw-r----- 1 kevin www-data 516 Mar 16 09:35 .env`

Answer (score 0):

If the artisan command doesn't work and you get the same error in the command line, that means composer didn't do a good job at getting all the files, you should delete the vendor folder and run `composer update` again.

Answer (score 0):

If you newly create a laravel project with command like `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel market` and deploy the new repo to the application path with cp command you may get this issue.

**I use laravel 5.4**

```
roofe@www:~/market$ php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 5.4.33
```

When you create the laravel project, you can see the the logs that create the key like this:

> Generating autoload files
>
> > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> >     php artisan optimize Generating optimized class loader The compiled services file has been removed.
> >     php artisan key:generate Application key [base64:exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/k=] set successfully.

By default the key config in the config/app.php is as follows, it use `AES-256-CBC` and the generated key when creating the project is stored in the `.env` file. If you use command like `cp -r ./* /var/www/market/` the `.env` file will not be moved to the application path.

> ```
> /*
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | Encryption Key
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |
> | This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
> | to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
> | will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
> |
> */
>
> 'key' => env('APP_KEY'),
>
> 'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
> ```

When I chage my deploy command to `cp -r ./* ./.env /var/www/market/`, this issue gone.

You also can refer to this github [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9080).

Answer (score 0):

run :

`composer dump-autoload`

delete .env

```bash
cp .env.example .env

php artisan key:generate

php artisan serve
```