# Laravel Runtimeexception error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, runtimeexception

With xampp I made a virtual host named leeromgeving.dev. But when I enter this in my bar its shows this. [image]

It worked before, I don't know what is causing this. If I need to provide some code. Please inform me.

Thanks for the answers but unfortunately none of them worked.
This is what I get now after typing this in [image][image]

Comment: See Here https://laravel.io/forum/06-04-2015-cipher-error and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39693312/the-only-supported-ciphers-are-aes-128-cbc-and-aes-256-cbc-with-the-correct-key

Comment: Check that you have a welcome.blade.php in your views directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Following Steps

```
-> delete .env file
-> copy .env.example .env
-> php artisan key:generate
-> remove env() in 'key' in config/app.php
```

or See https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/the-only-supported-ciphers-are-aes-128-cbc-and-aes-256-cbc-with-the-correct-key-lengths

Comment: I updated my question. I did what everyone says but it gave me another error

Answer (score 0):

you have to insert the `APP_KEY` in your `env` file, use this command to generate a new Application key

```
php artisan key:generate
```