# Laravel: The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I installed Laravel and uploaded it to git
now I downloaded it
But when I'm trying to enter the site I get this error:

> The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths.

I found this answer: [The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths. laravel 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39693312/the-only-supported-ciphers-are-aes-128-cbc-and-aes-256-cbc-with-the-correct-key)

My `config/app.php`

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

'cipher' => env('APP_KEY'),
```

I run

```
php artisan key:generate
```

my `ENV` file:

```
APP_KEY=base64:zJQUL0Kuwhb2JL6L7IJ+1UO7IUSQSw2Td40F9LNABfE=
```

I run `composer update`

but still the same error...
I tried to clear config and cache it but that didn't help.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your config/app.php is wrong, change the cipher entry to `'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC'`. You have key and cipher both pointing to the same .env variable.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way of resolving this is as follows:

```bash
php artisan key:generate (Note the generated base 64 key)

php artisan config:cache
```

Check the .env file and confirm that the value of `APP_KEY` is equal to the value you noted during `key:generate`

Thats it!!

Answer (score 1):

`php artisan key:generate`  fixed for me . You can check the .env to be sure the APP_KEY get assigned a base64 value

Answer (score 0):

APP_KEY cipher if AES-256-CBC is selected, the length must be 32 characters.

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

APP_KEY=base64:iT7PDx7j8yKVTj0AW81vTnEQmqLwnVfW    => 32 characters
```