# Refreshing again and again shows error message

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I was playing with Laravel by refreshing the page 10 times in a second and did this many times continuously. I got the below error

> The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the
>   correct key lengths.

This is a test case which can occur anytime by end user also. Is there any way to fix it?

I already have key in my env file. This issue occurs only when i refresh the page again and again,

**[I already checked the answer but could not help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39693312/the-only-supported-ciphers-are-aes-128-cbc-and-aes-256-cbc-with-the-correct-key)**

Comment: You've `.env` file in project ?

Comment: Yes it exists in the project.

Comment: Have you checked `cipher` in **config/app.php** ?

Comment: `'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',` this was present in the config/app.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths. laravel 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39693312/the-only-supported-ciphers-are-aes-128-cbc-and-aes-256-cbc-with-the-correct-key)

Comment: Look at this issue in git hub might help you
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9080

Comment: I have cleared config and cache both. Still same issue. I want to tell again that this issue occurs when you refresh the page over and over again continuously.

Comment: @Pankaj i have same problem with continuously firing Ajax request in laravel

Comment: just build the cache using `php artisan config:cache` this should solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

As posted by one of the users at [this issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9080) at GitHub,

Under a heavy load of requests, two async requests are made, and during the second request the .env file is locked, so you receive the error only for that request.

To solve this, you can create a cache using below command, which will bypass your `.env` file on further requests.

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Run following command from application folder:

```
$ php artisan key:generate
```

Answer (score 0):

First make the key if doesn't exists by running following command.

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Next clear your config cache.

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Propably application cached your config without app-key.