# php artisan serve command display error message

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am using php 7.3.2 on window 7. When I try to run `php artisan serve`, it shows this error on the webpage:

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

Is it related to the message that I received when I want to migrate database, it says

> Application In Production!

My error in laravel log shows

> production.ERROR: RuntimeException: The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths. in C:\xampp\htdocs\Inventory\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter.php:43

Comment: Please post the relating error in your `storage/logs/laravel.log` file

Comment: The error shows `production.ERROR: RuntimeException: The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths. in C:\xampp\htdocs\Inventory\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter.php:43`

Comment: You need to add a secret key. See below answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the error in your log file you seem to be missing your `key` attribute in your `.env`  file. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39693312/the-only-supported-ciphers-are-aes-128-cbc-and-aes-256-cbc-with-the-correct-key) SO question for a solution.

To generate the secret key, run

```
$ php artisan key:generate
```

make sure to follow the [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x#installation) when installing Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Your laravel is running in `production` mode. If you are developing local, you should switch that for your local maschine.

To do so: In your `.env` set the `APP_ENV` to `local` (`APP_ENV=local`) and try again.

Now, you will see the full error message and you are able to handle it now.

Comment: my `.env.exampe` file already put  `APP_NAME=Laravel`,
`APP_ENV=local`, 
`APP_KEY=`, 
`APP_DEBUG=true`,
`APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug`,
`APP_URL=http://localhost`

Comment: @irhamdollah Your key-value is missing. See below answer

Comment: @irhamdollah dont look `.env.example`, change in `.env` file

Comment: You have to look to your `.env`, not your `.env.example` for this is just a template

Comment: In case, you do not have an `.env`, copy the `.env.example` and rename it to `.env`, then execute on your cli `php artisan key:generate` and try again